# Duplicated data count as per baseline date

Tags: mysql, sql

I’d like to create a query that checks if there is any duplicated ID that has been used as per date.

To this end, 60 days prior to, not the subsequent to, the baseline date, should be reviewed for any duplication. 
A table example is as below.

```
CREATE TABLE SampleTable (
   pKey INT PRIMARY KEY,
   personalID INT NOT NULL,
   createDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
   value INT NULL
);
```

The baseline date corresponds to `DATE(createDate)` whereas ID to be checked for duplication is `personallD`. 
Information needed herein can boil down to the number of today’s data and that of duplicated data. 
The number of today’s data can be easily queried as follows.

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*)
FROM SampleTable
WHERE
   DATE(createDate) = DATE(NOW())
```

Out of today’s data, in addition, the number of duplicated data can be checked as follows.

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*)
FROM (
   SELECT
      personalID,
      COUNT(*)
   FROM SampleTable
   WHERE
      DATEDIFF(NOW(), trDate) <= 60
   GROUP BY personalID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS T
```

In conclusion, all I need to do is get the number of total data by date and the number of data that have the same `personalID` during the previous days.

[Sample Data]

```
pKey    personalID  createDate  value
1       1           2018-01-01  100
2       2           2018-01-01  300
3       3           2018-01-01  500
7       1           2018-01-02  100
8       2           2018-01-02  200
9       3           2018-01-02  200
10      4           2018-01-02  100
11      5           2018-01-02  100
12      3           2018-01-03  200
13      4           2018-01-03  100
14      5           2018-01-03  100
15      6           2018-01-03  50
```

[Desired result]

```
date        totalCount  duplicated
2018-01-01  3           0
2018-01-02  5           3
2018-01-03  4           3
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  I can't tell if you want ids with data on different days or ids that appear multiple times on the same day or ids that have data today and data in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the ids that have multiple rows in the past 60 days:

```
select personid
from sampledata
where trdate >= curdate() - interval 60 day
group by personid
having count(*) >= 2;
```

If you want to also insist that the `personid` appears on the most recent date:

```
select personid
from sampledata
where trdate >= curdate() - interval 60 day
group by personid
having count(*) >= 2 and date(max(trdate)) = curdate();
```

EDIT:

This seems to be what you want, assuming no duplicates on a given day

```
select trdate, count(*) as num_persons,
       sum(num_dups > 0) as num_dups
from (select sd.*,
             (select count(*)
              from sampledata sd2
              where sd2.personid = sd.personid and
                    sd2.trdate < sd.trdate and
                    sd2.trdate >= sd.trdate - interval 60 day
             ) as num_dups
      from sampledata
     ) sd
group by trdate;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, unfortunately, that's not I want. I updated sample data and desired result to clarify.

Comment: Works pretty fine. But, considering performance, will it be okay?

Comment: @KeithPark . . . An index on (personId, trdate)` would help performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the self join approach as well to find out this type of data. If you need to find out what ID repeated by comparing with previous dates , you can also use this approach.

```
Create table Testtbl (pkey int, personalID int, createddate date, value int); 

insert into Testtbl values 
(1  ,     1,           '2018-01-01' , 100) , 
(2 ,     2,           '2018-01-01' , 300) ,
(3  ,     3,           '2018-01-01' , 500) ,
(4  ,     1,           '2018-01-02' , 100) ,
(5  ,     2,           '2018-01-02' , 200) ,
(6  ,     3,           '2018-01-02' , 200) ,
(7  ,     4,           '2018-01-02' , 100) ,
(8  ,     5,           '2018-01-02' , 100) ,
(9  ,     3,           '2018-01-03' , 200) ,
(14  ,     3,           '2018-01-03' , 500) ,
(10  ,     4,           '2018-01-03' , 100) ,
(11  ,     5,           '2018-01-03' , 100) ,
(12  ,     6,           '2018-01-03' , 50),
(13  ,     6,           '2018-01-03' , 100)
```

Query: Left join will help to find out duplicated data without loss of total count. Distinct is to make sure that the same ID is not counted twice .

```
  select  t.createddate, count(Distinct t.pkey) TotalCount, 
  case when t.Createddate > t1.createddate  
  then Count(distinct t1.PersonalID) + case when t.Createddate = 
  t1.createddate and 
  t.personalID = t1.personalID  and t.pkey != t1.pkey then Count(distinct 
  t1.PersonalID) 
  else 0 end else 0     
  end   Duplicated   from Testtbl t 
  left join Testtbl t1 on t.personalID = t1.personalID 
                    and t.Createddate >= t1.Createddate and t.pkey != t1.pkey 
                    and DATEDIFF(t1.Createddate, t.Createddate) <= 60 
 Group by t.createddate
```

Output:

```
createddate  TotalCount Duplicated
2018-01-01     3         0
2018-01-02     5         3
2018-01-03     6         5
```

Comment: Your query doesn't consider duplication on the same day.

Comment: @KeithPark I thought it was comparison against previous days,I did not realize that. I added to consider same day duplication as well. If you see I added 6 and 3 on the same day, now the output will be 5 for duplicated (comparing all the unique IDs for previous days and within the same day as well and total count will be 6